# Videogame market analysis

Tags: distributions, data-visualization, histogram

I'm looking if there is a name for what I'm trying to do.

*TLDR: Market contains offers to exchange currency 1 for currency 2. I want to make a histogram showing total volumes of currency1 in specific price ranges, but making a histogram from the data shows number of offers in specific price ranges, not the amount of currency.*

Shortcuts I'm using:

- kk - millions (500kk = 500 million)
- kkk - billions (5kkk = 5 billion =5000kkk = 5000 million)

**Setup** - there's a market in a videogame where players go to place offers to exchange currency 1 (YANG) for currency 2 (SD). I calculate an extra statistic, which is a rate calculated with `1000*SD/YANG`, which is a rate that shows how much SD does 1kkk YANG cost.

**Example with an image:** Below you can see an image showing a snapshot of the market at some point in time. (I cropped out an unnecessary column). In row 0 we can see that a player is offering 10000kk YANG (10kkk YANG) for 2500SD. Rate in this case (kkkPrice) is 250 SD/kkk YANG.

[image: Image with data]

Now I wanted to analyze this, so I made some graphs, mainly histograms.

[image: Market graphs]

**Problem**: The problem for me lies in the bottom right graph. It's a histogram of the kkkPrice column, showing how many offers have which rate (bins are from 180 to 300 with step of 10)

We can see that in price range 250-260SD/kkk there are 97 offers out of 265 total (36.6%).
Now when I manually filter out those offers and sum it up, I find out that those 97 offers are for 48 658kk YANG out of 317 153kk YANG total (15.3%).

In other words, 36.6% of offers contain only 15.3% of all the YANG offered.

**This graphs shows how many offers are in each price range, but I would like to see how much YANG is in each price range.** I don't know what it is called and if there's some predefined or simple way to calculate it instead of doing it myself (filtering each price range and summing it).

Comment: There are no graphs to see in your question. Also, can you perhaps post an excerpt of the data you're using?

Comment: @IgorF. There are 2 images to see in my post. The links are https://i.imgur.com/cMdU73y.png and https://i.imgur.com/v9b3WpC.png . I guess you cant see them, otherwise I do not understand what you're saying.

Comment: Oh, I see. Obviously, our IT has (again!) changed the firewall settings :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This graphs shows how many offers are in each price range, but I would like to see how much YANG is in each price range. I don't know what it is called and if there's some predefined or simple way to calculate it instead of doing it myself (filtering each price range and summing it).

A weighted histogram does what you want. Most programming languages have a package/function for it that does it automatically.

In R: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plotrix/versions/3.8-2/topics/weighted.hist

Comment: Thank you so much, you are a godsend! I can't believe it was so simple, I completely forgot there was a weights option for a histogram. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for Market depth chart.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Market_depth

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).